# How do I properly reattach the Nikon D5100's internal display cable?

Tags: nikon, repair, rear-lcd

I have recently repaired my d5100, and on putting the back on I was not happy with the way that the 40 pin connector for the display went back, (it didn't feel right).

[image]

I now have no display but, every thing else seems to work fine.
The connector is one that I am not familiar with. How can I attach it properly?

Comment: It sounds like you're saying the repair went wrong. Was this something you did yourself, or did to come back wrong from a shop?

Comment: Yes I was replacing the mirror, which I achieved, but when I put it all back together no display.

Answer (score 1):

Most Nikons that I have taken apart use the flip-up type ribbon connectors, you have to flip up the top edge, insert ribbon and flip down. If you tried just pushing it in flat its unlikely to have gone in far enough.

This is a very common type of connector on electronics (Laptops, cameras etc)

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response, however t he plug and socket are different to what you have show.